# Can one still install hololens 1st gen emulator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

Hi I was trying to install the hololens 1st gen emulator off of the official website but the download link doesn't work, I am wondering if it just me or is the download link actually broken? I tried with the microsoft archive for the previous releases for the emulators as well but none of the 1st gen ones work
The link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools?tabs=unity

Comment: The link is up and healthy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have reproduced this issue with some third-party browsers. The actual behavior is the browser pops up a new tab and closes immediately without any download task starts.

For now, it is recommended that you use the [Edge browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge), after checking it can work fine on this link. Or, the workaround for some third-party browsers is to right-click the emulator download link and select `copy address link`, then paste it into the address bar.